# product loading error in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an error in `JQuery` code. Code must load products on the page. We clicked on the `li`, but homepage doesn't load the products, but other page loads there.

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".product-sort ul li a").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".product-sort ul li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");        
        var id = $(this).attr("catid");     
         $('.product-item').hide();
        $('.product-item').each(function() {fadeIn();});
        if($(this).attr("catid") == 1) {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            $(".product-item").each(function(){
                if ($(this).attr("cat") == id)
                    $(this).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: please post your html code

Comment: Please explain your scenario a little more.

Comment: <div class="content">
 <h1 class="section-header"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></h1>
 <div class="product-sort">
  <ul id="list-category">
   <li class="active"><a href="#" catid="1">Вся продукция</a></li>
   <?php $wcatTerms = get_terms('taxproduct', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0));
   
   foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) : 
      ?>
   <li><a href="#" catid="<?php echo $wcatTerm->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?></a></li>
   <?php 
      endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
 </div>

Comment: you should post your out hlml code here!!!

Comment: let me see, wait for minutes!

Comment: I took project on the freelance site... i known WordPress and HTMl and CSS, I do work, and all work, but yesterday i see that IT IS JQUERY didn't work, i don't known because

Comment: Why you wrote:     $(this).attr("catid") == 1

Comment: @VadimZlagoda look at my comment, it worked properly with me

Comment: @An Pham, Do you have a Telegramm? I have screenshot problem...and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, It worked properly with me! (my `div` `.product-item` just for test)

```
<div class="product-sort">
    <ul id="list-category">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" catid="1">Вся продукция</a>


        <li><a href="#" catid="c1">c1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" catid="c2">c2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" catid="c3">c3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" catid="c4">c4</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div class="product-item" cat="c1">C11</div>
<div class="product-item" cat="c1">C12</div>
<div class="product-item" cat="c2">C21</div>
<div class="product-item" cat="c2">C22</div>
<div class="product-item" cat="c3">C31</div>
<div class="product-item" cat="c4">C41</div>
<div class="product-item" cat="c4">C42</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".product-sort ul li a").on("click", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $(".product-sort ul li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
            var id = $(this).attr("catid");
            $('.product-item').hide();

            $(".product-item").each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("cat") == id)
                    $(this).fadeIn();
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `$(this)` in this line:

```
 $('.product-item').each(function() {$(this).fadeIn();});
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to call fadeIn on jquery instance

```
$(function(){
$(".product-sort ul li a").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".product-sort ul li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");        
    var id = $(this).attr("catid");     
     $('.product-item').hide();
    $('.product-item').each(function() {
       $(this).fadeIn(); // you forgot to call fadeIn on jquery object
    });
    if($(this).attr("catid") == 1) {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $(".product-item").each(function(){
            if ($(this).attr("cat") == id)
                $(this).fadeIn();
        });
      }
  }); 

});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".product-sort ul li a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".product-sort ul li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    var id = $(this).attr("catid");
    alert('selected category id '+id+'\n showing only those category items')
    $('.product-item').hide();    

      $(".product-item").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("cat") == id)
          $(this).fadeIn();
      });
   
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li.active >a {
color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="section-header"><span>Продукция</span></h1>
  <div class="product-sort">
    <ul id="list-category">
      <li class="active"><a href="#" catid="1">Вся продукция</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" catid="8">Кексы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" catid="9">Печенье</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" catid="5">Пирожные</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" catid="6">Рулеты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" catid="4">Торты</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">



    <div class="product-item" cat="4">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-mokko">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/70-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Торт «Мокко» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="4">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-belosnezhka">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/69-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Торт «Белоснежка» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>







    <div class="product-item" cat="6">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/rulet-biskvitnyy-s-varenym-sgushhennym">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/66-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Рулет «Бисквитный с вареным сгущенным молоком» целый </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="6">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/rulet-fruktovyy-nareznoy">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/65-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Рулет «Фруктовый» нарезной </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-item" cat="6">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/rulet-limonnik-slivochnyy-nareznoy">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/64-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Рулет «Лимонник сливочный» нарезной </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="6">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/rulet-limonnik-slivochnyy-celyy">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/64-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Рулет «Лимонник сливочный» целый </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="8">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/keks-tirolskiy-so-sgushhenkoy-v-karam">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/57-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Кекс «Тирольский » со сгущенкой в карамельной глазури </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-skazka-krem-karamel">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/56-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Сказка крем-карамель» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-viktoriya">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/55-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Виктория» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-lakomka-s-tryufelnoy-nachink">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/54-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Лакомка с трюфельной начинкой и орехами» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-ptiche-moloko">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/53-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Птичье молоко» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-fantaziya-v-karamelnoy-glaz">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/52-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Фантазия» в карамельной глазури </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="4">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/tort-smetannik">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/51-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Торт «Сметанник» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,4 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="4">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/tort-praga">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/50-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Торт «Прага» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,4 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-pancho-slivochno-vishnyovoe">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/49-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Панчо» сливочно-вишнёвое </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="4">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/tort-skazka">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/48-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Торт «Сказка» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="4">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/tort-kievskiy">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/47-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Торт «Киевский» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-milfoy-s-vishnevym-konfityur">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/35-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Мильфой с вишневым конфитюром» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="8">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/keks-tirolskiy-s-vishney">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/34-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Кекс «Тирольский» с вишней </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-magiya">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/33-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Магия» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="8">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/keks-tirolskiy-s-chernikoy">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/32-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Кекс «Тирольский» с черникой </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-tango-mindalno-karamelno">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/31-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Танго миндально-карамельное» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-melita">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/30-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Мелита» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="4">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/tort-leningradskoe">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/29-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Торт «Ленинградское» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,4 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="9">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pechene-skazka-sloenoe">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/28-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Печенье «Сказка слоеное» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-medovik">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/27-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Медовик» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-pancho-iriska">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/26-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Панчо» ириска </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-vostochnaya-skazka">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/25-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Восточная сказка» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-pchelka">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/24-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Пчелка» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-smetannik">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/22-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Сметанник» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="4">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-tort-skazka-krem-karamel">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/21-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Торт «Сказка крем-карамель» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,4 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-yekzotika">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/20-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Экзотика» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-pesochnoe-poloska-s-konfityur-3">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/19-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Песочное полоска с конфитюром в шоколадной глазури» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-pesochnoe-poloska-s-konfityur-2">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/19-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Песочное полоска с конфитюром в белой глазури» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-korolevskoe">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/18-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Королевское « </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-valentinka">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/17-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Валентинка» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-praga">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/16-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Прага» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-koketka">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/15-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Кокетка» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-leningradskoe">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/14-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Ленинградское» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-chyornyy-princ">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/13-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Чёрный принц» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-zimnyaya-vishnya">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/12-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Зимняя вишня» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-pyanaya-vishnya">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/12-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Пьяная вишня» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">3 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-belochka-slivochnaya">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/10-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Белочка сливочная» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-belochka-shokoladnaya">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/9-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Белочка шоколадная» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-damskiy-kapriz">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/8-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Дамский каприз» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-imperatorskoe-v-beloy-glaz">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/7-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Императорское в белой глазури» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-imperatorskoe-v-shokoladno">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/6-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Императорское в шоколадной глазури» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="8">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/keks-tirolskiy-s-yagodami-klubniki">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/5-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Кекс «Тирольский» с ягодами клубники </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="4">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/tort-romeo-i-dzhuleta">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/4-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Торт «Ромео и Джульета» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,4 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-chernyy-les">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/3-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Черный лес» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="product-item" cat="5">
      <a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-aysberg">
        <div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/2-170x160.jpg);"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="product-item-bottom">
        <div class="product-item__title">
          Пирожное «Айсберг» </div>
        <div class="product-item__weight">2,5 кг</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @VadimZlagoda plz provide generated html

Comment: Sorry, it is my first question...i don't known how it do

Comment: just on rendered page, copy html from developers tool

Comment: now you are being lazy.. anyways let me help you there

Comment: Stack Overflow say that it is very long message...it is my first questions...idon't known how this load code

Comment: <div class="content"><h1 class="section-header"><span>Продукция</span></h1><div class="product-sort"><ul id="list-category"><li class="active"><a href="#" catid="1">Вся продукция</a></li></ul></div><div class="product-wrapper"><div class="product-item" cat="4"><a href="http://tpkviktoriya.ru/tproduct/pirozhnoe-mokko"><div class="product-item__img" style="background-image: url(http://tpkviktoriya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/70-170x160.jpg);"></div></a><div class="product-item-bottom"><div class="product-item__title">Торт &#&#187;</div><div class="product-item__weight">2 кг</div></div></div>

Comment: its ok.. I got the html from your site.. check updated answer

Comment: Very BIG THANK YOU!!! I write this code, but if i click on the li Вся продукция, all eat deleted(the problem is not solved)

Comment: Make sure bcr.. has catid which is in products-items cat

Comment: Cool.. then can you plz accept it as answer @VadimZlagoda